# Query inside loop

Tags: php, loops, pdo

So I have a function that allows me to get some extra information about a player based on his ID.

```
function get_player_details($id,$select="*") {
    include("includes/database.php");
    $results = $db->prepare("SELECT " . $select . " FROM `wp_users` WHERE `ID` = ?");
    $results->bindParam(1,$id);
    $results->execute();
    $player = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($player === false){
      return $player;
    } else {
      return $player;
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to use the function inside a loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `unban_requests` WHERE `Player` = :player && `solved` = :solved";
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sql);
$preparedStatement->execute(array(
                    ':player' => $logged_info["ID"],
                    ':solved' => 0
                ));
$data = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
if($data !== false && $preparedStatement->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $info = get_player_details($row["player"],"`username`");
        echo $info["username"];
    }
}
```

Everything works just fine, the problem is that having the query inside the loop makes the page to load too slow. How can I optimize my code?

Comment: You can use the IN function and supply that with an array of id's. That way you don't have to loop through all the players, but you can just use one query.

Comment: Can you give me a code example, please?

Comment: How many entries are in the table?

Comment: 140k in wp_users table.

Comment: @Marius see my answer. have any question let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code.

It will get All Player IDs and then run ONLY one query to get all the records of all players intead of RUNNING MULTIPLE queries.

```
<?php

function get_player_details($id,$select="*") {
    include("includes/database.php");

    // implode() will generate your IDs like  12, 122, 23
    $query = "SELECT " . $select . " FROM `wp_users` WHERE `ID` IN( " . implode(", " , $all_player_ids) . ");"
    echo $query;
    $results = $db->prepare($query);

    $results->execute();
    $player = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($player === false){
      return $player;
    } else {
      return $player;
    }
}






$sql = "SELECT * FROM `unban_requests` WHERE `Player` = :player && `solved` = :solved";
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sql);
$preparedStatement->execute(array(
                    ':player' => $logged_info["ID"],
                    ':solved' => 0
                ));
$data = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
if($data !== false && $preparedStatement->rowCount() > 0){

    $all_player_ids = array();
    // Get all the Player IDs and append to array
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $all_player_ids[] = $row['player'];
    }


    $all_player_usernames = get_player_details($all_player_ids, "username");

    foreach($all_player_usernames as $arr){
        echo $arr['username'];

    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Umair and sorry for the late answer, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using var_dump for $all_player_usernames and it only returns one entry:  array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(5) "Admin" }. And when I'm trying to echo $arr I get a warning: Warning: Illegal string offset 'username'

Comment: @Marius see the statemetn ` echo $query;` it will print your query ... copy that query and run in your PHPmyAdmin directly to verify that what it actually returns

Comment: I've solved it, the problem was in the fetching method. Instead of fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) I've used fetchAll() and now it works. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is a LEFT JOIN, assuming player field in table 1 equals ID field in table 2.

`` SELECT * FROM `unban_requests` WHERE `Player` = :player && `solved` = :solved LEFT JOIN `wp_users` ON unban_requests.player=wp_users.ID; ``

Another speedup is to create indexes on fields `player` and `solved` if you don't have them yet.